# jQuery Animate On Click Toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on mimicking chanel's footer animation but I just can't seem to get it right. The site location where I am testing is [here](http://elixdesigns.com/gisell). On [chanels](http://www.chanel.com/) site, whenever a user scrolls or clicks more the footer becomes 100% covering the div in the background. I have achieved the 100% height but my jquery animate does not work. Any help?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".handle").toggle(function() {
            //$('#footer').animate(),
            $('#footer').animate({top: "0px"}, 1000);
        }, function() {
            //$('#footer').removeClass('animateHeight'),
            $('#footer').css("top", "");
            //$('#footer').animate({bottom: "0"}, "slow");
       });
      });
</script>
```

I know it has to do with .css("top", ""); as it does not animate but removes the css but thats the only way I can get the footer to go back to the bottom. Help? - Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve, or what your problem is really? i wish i could help but i have too many option for you right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css to your `footer`

```
#footer {
    top: 92%;
}
```

and change your code to this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".handle").toggle(function() {
            $('#footer').animate({top: "0px"}, 1000);
        }, function() {
            $('#footer').animate({top: "92%"}, 1000);            
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script as follows:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $(".handle").toggle(function() {
                $('#footer').animate({top: "0px"}, 1000);
            }, function() {
                $('#footer').animate({top: "null"}, 1000);
           });
         });
    </script>
```